# Spotify AUTHENTICATION SERVICE UNKNOWN_ERROR kotlin android

Tags: android, kotlin, spotify

I am trying authenticate user with spotify app and spotify auth API (implementation 'com.spotify.android:auth:2.0.1') followed the steps mentioned in Spotify SDK github sample
my code:

`Added in gradle(app.module) defaultConfig { manifestPlaceholders = [redirectSchemeName: "appname", redirectHostName:"spotify_login_callback"] }`

```
// Fragment/Activity

val CLIENT_ID = "7bf56252cd644b339cc97df5b4d7eeee"
val AUTH_TOKEN_REQUEST_CODE = 0x10
val AUTH_CODE_REQUEST_CODE = 0x11

var mAccessToken: String? = null
var mAccessCode: String? = null

fun onRequestTokenClicked() {
        val request = getAuthenticationRequest(AuthorizationResponse.Type.TOKEN)
        AuthorizationClient.openLoginActivity(requireActivity(), AUTH_TOKEN_REQUEST_CODE, request)
    }

 fun onRequestCodeClicked() {
        val request: AuthorizationRequest =
            getAuthenticationRequest(AuthorizationResponse.Type.CODE)
        AuthorizationClient.openLoginActivity(requireActivity(), AUTH_CODE_REQUEST_CODE, request)
    }

 private fun getAuthenticationRequest(type: AuthorizationResponse.Type): AuthorizationRequest {
        return AuthorizationRequest.Builder(
            CLIENT_ID,
            type,
            getRedirectUri().toString()
        )
            .setShowDialog(false)
                //  "user-read-email"
            .setScopes(arrayOf("user-read-email")) // user-read-private , "streaming"
            .build()
    }

  private fun getRedirectUri(): Uri? {
        return Uri.Builder()
            .scheme("appname")
            .authority("spotify_login_callback")
            .build()
    }

 val response = AuthorizationClient.getResponse(resultCode, data)
        if (response.error != null && !response.error.isEmpty()) {
            setResponse(response.error)
            Toast.makeText(requireActivity(),"Error: response.error"+response.error,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
        if (requestCode == AUTH_TOKEN_REQUEST_CODE) {
            mAccessToken = response.accessToken
            Toast.makeText(requireActivity(),"AccessToken: "+mAccessToken,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            updateTokenView()
        } else if (requestCode == AUTH_CODE_REQUEST_CODE) {
            mAccessCode = response.code
            Toast.makeText(requireActivity(),"AccessCode"+mAccessCode,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
```

This code prints log "Spotify auth completing. The response is in EXTRA with key response" after debugging library gives AUTHENTICATION SERVICE UNKNOWN_ERROR does anyone know the cause of this error, same code provided in SDK sample works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error and I was able to solve it. Your problem is that your redirect URI is not registered in the Spotify dashboard. So to solve this problem you'll have to set redirect url in the Spotify dashboard and use it in your code. If you want more data just set your Logcat to tag:spotify and you will see more information about the error.